# Downloading webpage source code with NSUrl

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm porting a bash script in obj-c. Currently in the bash script I do 'curl http://... > file.txt' to download and save the webpage source code.

I played around with NSUrl, but I didn't get it to work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this –

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourURL];
[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Note that this is a synchronous method so it will block until data is downloaded.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna try it. The synchronous method shouldn't be a matter as the source code is around 528 kb.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to use NSUrl, just use the initWithString: method and put in your url with the @"string" format.

Comment: I got this part, i'm looking for the simpliest way to initialize the download of the source code and save it to a file

Comment: Sorry for giving to simple of an answer. I am new to all of this.